# CUDA kernel call: kernel<<<...,...>>> where the third "<" is underlined red

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2017

I use the `CUDA 9.1` and `visual stdio 2017 15.4.4` to accelerate the computing and I get some problem when I edit the code in the visual stdio. Although I can compile the project correctly, the third `"<"` is **underlined red** when I call the kernel like: `kernel<<<...,...>>>`.

I am really know that it seems to be a minor problem but it does hinder my work because I was misled by the wrong information when debugging the code.

Sometimes the same thing happens with the include files like `#inclide <cstdlib>` and other kernel function when the first time I open the project file.

I can make sure that all paths are correctly added to the configuration and the code can be compile,run correctly.

Anyone who has idea about how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new project under the NVidia/CUDA and copy your code there. It should help the compiler understand. Otherwise triple "<" sign is not allowed in C code that's what It's giving you an error. I don't think you can get rid of the red underlines of the kernel invocation, besides I think it helps highlighting kernel invocations when you have so many in the program. Though the compiler shouldn't give you an error when compiling. 
To come back to your include problem, you might be forgetting to add references or referencing wrong :)
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I solve the problem by reinstalling the visual stdio,but the "<" still under the red line. just like u has mentioned,I have been accustomed to it ,sometimes it help me locate the position of the kernel function in the project :) Thanks a lot ~